# How to change color of hidden legend item instead of strike-through in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I was looking at this code and added ctx.fillStyle = 'red', and got this. I click on eBooks to hide its data but instead of eBooks being red, Microforms and Audiovisuals Mats were changed to red. [image]

```
var fillText = function(x, y, legendItem, textWidth) 
{
    ctx.fillText(legendItem.text, boxWidth + (fontSize / 2) + x, y);

    if (legendItem.hidden) {
        // Strikethrough the text if hidden
        //ctx.beginPath();
        //ctx.lineWidth = 2;
        //ctx.moveTo(boxWidth + (fontSize / 2) + x, y + (fontSize / 2));                                                
        //ctx.lineTo(boxWidth + (fontSize / 2) + x + textWidth, y + (fontSize / 2));
        //ctx.stroke();
        ctx.fillStyle = 'red'; //added here                                                
    }                                
};
```

Comment: Could you add your full code which reproduces the error, either by editing your question or adding a link to [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) for isntance. From what you currently have, we don't know how and where `fillText()` is called and then can't help you.

Comment: I didn't do anything special in my code. The code you are looking at is in charts.js which can be found online. I made these changes within charts.js to get this result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take a look at the [`fillStyle` doc on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillStyle) :

> The CanvasRenderingContext2D.fillStyle property of the Canvas 2D API specifies the color or style to use inside shapes.

So it will have an effect on the **next** shapes (*such as text via* `fillText`).

---

You need to change the style of the text before writing it down.

Using the same function you put in your question :

```
var fillText = function(x, y, legendItem, textWidth) 
{
    // We store the current fillStyle
    var prevFillStyle = ctx.fillStyle;

    if (legendItem.hidden) {
        // If the item is hidden, we change the fillStyle to red
        ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    }

    // The legend label is written here
    ctx.fillText(legendItem.text, boxWidth + (fontSize / 2) + x, y);

    if (legendItem.hidden) {
        // We comment the stroke part -- as you did
        //ctx.beginPath();
        //ctx.lineWidth = 2;
        //ctx.moveTo(boxWidth + (fontSize / 2) + x, y + (fontSize / 2));
        //ctx.lineTo(boxWidth + (fontSize / 2) + x + textWidth, y + (fontSize / 2));
        //ctx.stroke();

        // And then we put the fillStyle back to its previous value
        ctx.fillStyle = prevFillStyle;                                              
    }                                
};
```

And here is the final result :
[image]

Comment: For those who wonder where this function comes from; it does directly [from the source code](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/master/src/core/core.legend.js#L352-L363) of Chart.js.

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm!

Comment: amazing but is it possible to reproduce the same behaviour in react-chartjs-2?

Answer (score 1):

I found a better way doing that:

add onClick to legends and put this :

```
      const index = legendItem.datasetIndex;
      const ci = legend.chart;
      const isVisible = ci.isDatasetVisible(index);
      ci.setDatasetVisibility(index, !isVisible);
   

      // this is where the stroke remove happens
      const ci = legend.chart;

      const fillTextValue = ci.ctx.fillText;
      ci.ctx.fillText = function fillText(x, v, b) {
        fillTextValue.bind(ci.ctx, x, v, b)();
        this.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0)"; // whatever color you like
      };
      ci.update();
```